# Iphone+Xcode+Badge "A" or "M" resembles what?

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4.2

In Xcode, in the navigation area on the left, next to a few files, on the right there is a little icon badge, `M` or sometimes `A`.

What is that for?

Is there any option that I left selected while creating New Project or are any project settings responsible for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this responds to your git/svn repository

source: [Apple Dev Library: Managing Versions of your Project](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/SCM/SCM.html)

```
M
Locally modified

U    
Updated in repository

A
Locally added    

D
Locally deleted

I
Ignored

R
Replaced in the repository

–
The contents of the folder have mixed status; display the contents to see individual status

?
Not under source control
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because you might have selected option as shown in below image when you created your application project, so this creates a repository for your application:

[image]

```
A indicates Added Files
M indicates Modified Files which are came by default with project
```

Comment: +1 for good answer. But you need to explain a bit more, which I have done this time.

Answer (score 1):

NO it just shows you the file is A for Added and M for Modified by user

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because you enabled Git SCM when you created the project. M means modified, and A means added. When you commit the changes the markers will disappear.